# Marketing Cloud Content Builder WYSIWYG editor for multiple languages

Tags: content-builder, translation, language

Is there an easy way to have a block element with a single WYSIWYG editor for multiple languages?
I want to have an element similar to the image carousel but with text.

1. Default text field (Shown in the builder view)
2. Add Button to add multiple fields for languages.

Or is there a better way to have translated emails?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a good workaround by using some css styles for the editor view and some AMP IF/ELSE scripting.

The editor does only show the first language, but by editing the text block, all other languages are editable. By that the preview always looks like the final email.

All AMP scripts are also hidden in the editor view and those blocks do have a small visible language label.

[image]

## CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .amp, .amp .code {
      display: none;
    }
    [class*="editor-mode"] .multilanguage ~ * {
      display: none;
    }
    [class*="editor-mode"] .amp {
      display: block;
      height: 1px;
      position: relative;
    }
    [class*="editor-mode"] .amp.text {
      background: red;
    }
    [class*="editor-mode"] .amp.text:before {
      content: "AMP CODE";
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 2px 5px;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 10px;
      background: red;
      pointer-events: none;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
    }
    [class*="editor-mode"] .amp.text.lang.en:before { content: "EN" }
    [class*="editor-mode"] .amp.text.lang.de:before { content: "DE" }
</style>
```

### HTML

```
<!-- EN -->
<div class="multilanguage">
    <div class="amp text lang en">
        <div class="code">
            %%[ IF @Language == "EN" THEN ]%%
        </div>
    </div>
    
    LOCALIZED CONTENT EN

    <div class="amp notext">
        <div class="code">
            %%[ ENDIF ]%%
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- DE -->
<div class="multilanguage">
    <div class="amp text lang de">
        <div class="code">
            %%[ IF @Language == "DE" THEN ]%%
        </div>
    </div>
    
    LOCALIZED CONTENT DE

    <div class="amp notext">
        <div class="code">
            %%[ ENDIF ]%%
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```